# Qual código, que transforme todos os links do site em outro, abrir em uma pagina personalizada com temporizador de 10 seg e dps botao d down

Tags: javascript, html

Qual código, que transforme todos os links de download do site em outro link, que vá abrir em uma pagina personalizada com temporizador de 10 segundos e depois dos 10 segundos apareça o botão de download. Por exemplo, todos os links do site são do mediafire, fazer com que todos esses links desse dominio, leve a uma nova pagina personalizada com o temporizador de 10 segundos, e depois de esperar esse tempo aparece o botão de download que leva para o link para baixar no mediafire

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.